# File upload with preserving the ajax controls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am having a small problem with file uploading.

So there is a button that you click and a window comes up( ajax powered), you select your file and press upload. The problem is as soon as the file gets uploaded to the browser the page reloads and closes the window. And there is no file :(. I have tested the codes without the window and they work greatly fine. What do you recommend?

here are my codes for upload

```
    <html>
<body>

<h2 class="">Step 1: Add the video</h2>

<p class="note">Your text goes here</p>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
<br/><br/>
Browse: <input type="file" name="file"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" id='button' Value="Upload the video file" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$filename=$_POST["name"];
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$size=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
$size=$size/1000000;
$size=round($size, 2);
$size.="MB";
$namewithext=$filename." (".$size.")".".".$ext;
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    if (file_exists("../../../moreinfo/files/videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo "<script> alert('".$_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. "."');</script>";
      }
    else
      {

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../../../moreinfo/files/videos/" . $namewithext);
      echo "<script> alert('"."success"."');</script>";


      }
    }
}
  else
  {

  }
?>
<?php
foreach(glob('../../../moreinfo/files/videos/*.*') as $filename){
     $name = str_replace('../../../moreinfo/files/videos/', '', $filename);
     $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $notneeded=".".$ext;
     $name = str_replace($notneeded, '', $name);
     echo $name."</br>";
 }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that `echo "<script> alert('"."success"."');</script>";` never gets executed because there is no time for that.

Thanks!

Comment: try to alert before if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) this line...and see if its going there...

Comment: Could you post your javascript also?

Comment: Your PHP script isn't designed to be used with AJAX, it's for normal form submission.

Comment: Yes Barmar, thats what i am thinking. Thanks! I will have to make a new thread to ask about ajax file uploads. I have worked with asp.net ajax but not regular ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

with

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

if this is not issue then try

```
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>"; exit;
```

and see if there is any error.

Comment: FYI if you do not write action it default go to same page

Comment: @NullPointer can you provide some document on it...because i don't know it.

Comment: it's partially what i want. There is a catch though, the page gets redirected to the actual page which is not meant to be seen outside the window.

And thanks so much!

Comment: See step 8 in [Form submission algorithm](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm)

Comment: @Barmar it says empty string, not undefined